# moveToElement does not trigger mouse over event

Tags: java, selenium, mouse, mouseover

The problem is related to test this [sortable list](https://camohub.github.io/jquery-sortable-lists/) plugin. I need to move the cursor to element A then make a click and hold (drag) this element and move to another element B. Then wait one second and then release dragged element A. The second element B should open a new placeholder for dragged element A.

The problem is that element B should know that the cursor is above it and should open the placeholder. But it does not react. Element B listens for the mouse move event, but I am not sure if `moveToElement()` triggers this event at all. I have a code that works fine but does not open the placeholder.

```
public void dragSubcategoryOutOfParentCategory(String parentCategoryText, String subCategoryText)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver());

    SelenideElement parentCategory = $$("#main .sortable li").get(0);
    SelenideElement subCategory = parentCategory.find("ul li");

    HashMap<String, Integer> parentTopLeftOffset = getElementTopLeftOffset(parentCategory);
    HashMap<String, Integer> subCategoryTopLeftOffset = getElementTopLeftOffset(subCategory);

    // Move cursor to top left corner
    actions.moveToElement(subCategory, subCategoryTopLeftOffset.get("x"), subCategoryTopLeftOffset.get("y")).perform();

    actions.clickAndHold().perform();

    // Move cursor to top left corner + 3px
    actions.moveToElement(parentCategory, parentTopLeftOffset.get("x") + 3, parentTopLeftOffset.get("y") + 3).perform();

    sleep(5000);

    actions.release().build().perform();

}
```

Here is the screenshot that I want

[image]

And here is the screenshot that I have

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I write this question I tried to simulate mousemove event by little steps over the element B and it works. So the code now looks like:

```
public void dragSubcategoryOutOfParentCategory(String parentCategoryText, String childCategoryText)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver());

    SelenideElement parentCategory = $$("#main .sortable li").get(0);
    SelenideElement childCategory = parentCategory.find("ul li");

    HashMap<String, Integer> parentTopLeftOffset = getElementTopLeftOffset(parentCategory);
    HashMap<String, Integer> childTopLeftOffset = getElementTopLeftOffset(childCategory);


    actions.moveToElement(childCategory, childTopLeftOffset.get("x"), childTopLeftOffset.get("y")).perform();
    actions.clickAndHold().perform();
    actions.moveToElement(parentCategory, parentTopLeftOffset.get("x") + 4, parentTopLeftOffset.get("y") + 4).perform();
    // Needs to simulate mousemove over the parent element,
    // otherwise it does not open new hint holder.
    sleep(250);
    actions.moveToElement(parentCategory, parentTopLeftOffset.get("x") + 3, parentTopLeftOffset.get("y") + 3).perform();
    sleep(250);
    actions.moveToElement(parentCategory, parentTopLeftOffset.get("x") + 2, parentTopLeftOffset.get("y") + 2).perform();
    sleep(1000);
    actions.release().build().perform();

    sleep(5000);
}
```